# Azure Active Directory Error: AADSTS20031: The supplied wctx is not valid

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Without changing anything in my web.config nor anything else that in my knowlage should have any impact on my application's authentication through AAD, I receive this Error:

> AADSTS20031: The supplied wctx is not valid. This can be caused by
>   caching redirect responses or using an incorrect URL to access the
>   service.

I did published an update, but as far as I know it does not have anything to do with it.

If I open a new tab and log-in to my application I am authenticated. the problem seems to be with the redirection to my application.

I will appreciate any lead on how to overcome this obstacle.

Comment: Are you still facing this problem? Can you provide some more details? A fiddler trace dump would be the best.

Comment: it started last Friday and next day it was fixed - without any action on my side... today it happed again. I don't know the reason. If anyone does I will highly appriciate any info on how to resolve this error, though I guess its something from microsoft side.

Comment: Got it - but need more data to troubleshoot. Could you provide a fiddler trace of failing request and response?